# What really happens during hybris update?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Does it backup whole database and then reload the data after update? or just adds/removes the affected columns and data in those columns?

Comment: You can find more information about the initialization and update in Hybris here: https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Initialization+and+Update+of+the+hybris+Commerce+Suite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention when you update a system Hybris will look for impex files matching

> projectdata*.impex

When you run initializaton Hybris also look for files matching

> essentialdata*.impex

So your question your question Hybris will simply reload data, from projectdata files (pattern could be override on your local.properties file)

Answer (score 0):

Run the dryrun and you can see exactly what it will do.

Answer (score 0):

During an update, type system definitions are modified to match the new type system definition in the items.xml files.   You can understand what exactly it do by reading [This page](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Initialization+and+Update+of+the+hybris+Commerce+Suite#InitializationandUpdateofthehybrisCommerceSuite-Update)

Answer (score -2):

Just   to  elaborate  on  Ram  Tripathi's  answer ...

Entire Type System Is Discarded & Re-Created from the Extension - `items.xml`.

Comment: when ? during Upd or Init ? I know it is obvious but you cant just answer so vaguely, and if it is to elaborate on Ram's, your answer is plain wrong.